# Flask - socket.error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: python, sockets, flask

Re-opening this question upon request ([error: [Errno 10053]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17854713/error-errno-10053)), providing the minimal testable example:

```
import time
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='static', template_folder='templates')

@app.route('/')
def main():
    return render_template('test.html')

@app.route('/test')
def test():
    print "Sleeping. Hit Stop button in browser now"
    time.sleep(10)
    print "Woke up. You should see a stack trace from the problematic exception below."
    return render_template('test.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="/test">test</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Guide:
Run the app, navigate to localhost:port, click on the link, then hit Stop button in your browser. You should see the exception once the sleep finishes.
The sleep is necessary to simulate any sort of activity happening on the server. It could be just a few seconds: if user manages to navigate away from the page - Flask will crash.

> socket.error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by
>   the software in your host machine

Why does the server stop serving the application? What other server can I use for my Flask application to avoid this?

Comment: if you serve it through one of the recommended ways (ie apache or nginx) this likely will not be an issue at all ...

Comment: I responded to a similar issue with exactly the same answer before, so I duplicated this to that (the other question is about concurrent requests but stopping `curl` then leads to the broken pipe traceback).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is an issue with the Python 2 implementation of the `SocketServer` module, it is not present in Python 3 (where the server keeps on serving).

Your have 3 options:

- Don't use the built-in server for production systems (it is a *development* server after all). Use a proper WSGI server like [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) or [uWSGI](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/),
- Enable threaded mode with `app.run(threaded=True)`; the thread dies but a new one is created for future requests,
- Upgrade to Python 3.

Comment: Confirming: upgraded to Python3 and the issue is no longer present. Thank you!

Comment: I'm using Python3 in my virtual environment, still I get this in my Django app.

Comment: @CoolCK: without a [MCVE] I can't help you, sorry.