# Ajax ABORT leads to Django errno 10053 - An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: ajax, django

I have a web-page (Django 1.9 on back-end, Apache server) with an endless-paginated table with large data set and column filters. When a user activates one filter (let's denote it **CHOICE 1**), and then instantly changes his mind resetting the filter (let's refer to it as **CHOICE 2**), I would like to tell Ajax to give up waiting for back-end response to CHOICE 1 and go on to posting and waiting for CHOICE 2 request. For this purpose, I had the following JS code:

```
// AJAX_GET_REQUEST is a global variable
AJAX_GET_REQUEST= $.ajax(
    {
        type:'GET',
        url:"/my_url/",
        beforeSend : function()
        {           
            if (AJAX_GET_REQUEST!= null)
                AJAX_GET_REQUEST.abort();
        },
        data:data,  
        success: function(response) 
        {
            // Do something
        }
    });
```

Fine. I used to think that I achieved the goal of successfully canceling irrelevant requests, But I found out that `AJAX_GET_REQUEST.abort();` leads to Django error `[Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine`. The interesting think is that this is not a 'fatal error' in that the app does not terminate, but rather it takes years for my paginated table to load. Django seems to reactivate connection itself and go on to handle last request. Finally after waiting for long time I see the correct result on front-end. If I remove the `AJAX_GET_REQUEST.abort();` line, everything is fine, but I have to wait until Django is through with irrelevant requests until it goes on to handle the last relevant request.
Is there any way out? Is it possible to abort previous requests avoiding this annoying 10053 error ?

Comment: Guessing you're using Python 2 as well? That's a pattern I'm noticing in this question. The answer here indicates it's a defect in SocketServer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40247025/flask-socket-error-errno-10053-an-established-connection-was-aborted-by-the?rq=1