# Python: HTTPS using a proxy server with requests

Tags: python, https, proxy, python-requests

I'm using MyIPHide. I downloaded their client software, installed it and have the service turned on.

I can access `https` websites fine with a browser but I cannot use `requests` to get the pages

This works:

```
import requests
IP=requests.get('http://api.ipify.org').text

proxyDict = { "http"  : IP,
              "https"  : IP
            }

url='http://www.cnn.com'
r=requests.get(url,proxies=proxyDict)
```

This doesn't:

```
url='https://www.cnn.com'
r=requests.get(url,proxies=proxyDict)
```

only difference is `http` vs `https`

here is the traceback:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 502, in send
    raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.cnn.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error(10053, 'An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine')))
```

I've tried other `https` websites, they all don't work.

I have also emailed support at MyIPHide. They said all proxies support `https`, which is true when I use a browser only.

One work around that works is if I use `Selenium` and get the page, then use `driver.page_source` for text.

It's not a proxy server problem because I have bought a private proxy server address through sslprivateproxy.com and put in the IP and port and I still get the same errors.

I'm using Python 2.7.15 and requests 2.20.1. Non proxy use of requests works, ie:

```
import requests
url='https://www.cnn.com'
r=requests.get(url)

>>> r
<Response [200]>
>>>
```

Also tried python 3.6 with requests 2.20.1 --> same results.

Comment: did you add the port? {"https":"ip:port"}. Or try `{"https":"183.88.219.163:57457"}`

Comment: i don't think you need to. there is no port specified.

Comment: If my proxy work for you that means the issue occured on your proxy

Comment: @kcorlidy. Thanks for the proxy. It looks like it also doesn't work. `ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.cnn.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000000003CD9208>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',)))`

Comment: yes, not all nodes work for me too. But also you can find one on https://free-proxy-list.net/. If you still go wrong. Tell me your platform,Python version and requests version, in order to i can get same error as you then find a solution.

Comment: @kcorlidy. I think the problem is here. Python2 problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40247025/flask-socket-error-errno-10053-an-established-connection-was-aborted-by-the . it seems like the `app.run(threaded=True)` would be the easist. How do I put that in the code?

Comment: @jason, how did you solve this? I am having same issue. Requests 2.22

Comment: I didn't. I didn't have to use it anymore.

Answer (score 2):

On requests it based on PoolManager size, so if you want to have more connection in pool you can reset the size of `HTTPAdapter()`. The way like that(to ensure if it works you can set to 0).

```
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter

proxy = {"http":"118.174.233.31:51726",
        "https":"43.254.132.86:50659"} # free proxy,often need to modify

with requests.Session() as se:
    # pool_connections=pool_maxsize=0 -> pool closed
    se.mount('https://', HTTPAdapter(pool_connections=100,pool_maxsize=100)) 
    se.mount('http://', HTTPAdapter(pool_connections=100,pool_maxsize=100))
    print(se.adapters["https://"]._pool_maxsize)
    #print(se.get("https://github.com"))
    print(se.get('http://api.ipify.org',proxies=proxy).text)

#100
#118.174.233.31
```

Comment: Ran on Windows10, Python27, requests-2.20.1

Comment: Thanks for trying, but I still get the same error when I make a page request. `url='https://www.cnn.com'
r=se.get(url,proxies=proxy)` gives me `ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.cnn.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error(10053, 'An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine')))`

Comment: what about your requests_version, and can you access website without https proxy?

Comment: yes I can. `requests == 2.18.4`. I just upgraded to `2.20.1`. Same error. I'm running python 2.7.15